# Calling a main-like function using argv[]

Tags: c++, zip, zlib, program-entry-point

I have some code here to call minizip(), a boilerplate dirty renamed main() of the minizip program, but when I compile, I get *undefined reference to `minizip(int, char**)*. Here's the code.

```
int minizip(int argc, char* argv[]);

void zipFiles(void)
{
 char arg0[] = "BBG";
 char arg1[] = "-0";
 char arg2[] = "out.zip";
 char arg3[] = "server.cs";

 char* argv[] = {&arg0[0], &arg1[0], &arg2[0], &arg3[0], 0};

 int argc = (int)(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])) - 1;

 minizip(argc, argv);
}

int minizip(argc,argv)
    int argc;
    char *argv[];
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: 0% Acceptence Rate!!!!!!!!! Good luck getting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is all of that code in the same file?  If not, and if the caller is C++ code and `minizip` is C code, the caller might need the `minizip` declaration within an `extern "C"` block to indicate that it will be calling a C function and therefore will need C linkage.

(Also, don't retype error messages.  Copy and paste them so that they are exact.  In this case, the compiler most likely reported an undefined reference to `minizip(int, char**)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you declaring the function arguments again in:

```
int minizip(argc,argv)
    int argc;
    char *argv[];
{
    ...
}
```

It' should say

```
int minizip(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: It's the legacy "K&R C" (pre-ISO) style for declaring function parameters.